# Combining criteria for BeforeSave event

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I need some assistance with BeforeSave VBA event.

I've introduced an additional criteria using Conditional Formatting to highlight a cell if it does not equal 10 characters.

Issue is, I already have a BeforeSave event in VBA to check if a checkbox is checked, how can I combine these two statements so that it checks these two criteria before saving?

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Cancel = Not Worksheets(1).CheckBoxes(1).Value = 1

Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    If rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
        MsgBox ("Please correct any fields highlighted in red")
    Exit For
    End If
Next rng

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If Cancel Then MsgBox "Please accept the terms and conditions before saving the Invoice"

End Sub
```

The highlighted criteria is the one I used to evaluate the checkbox, in between is the code I'm attempting to check for any cells filled in red. Also a sample in an excel sheet. 
[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please include your actual code in the post instead of a picture of the code.

Comment: Sorry about that, added. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close! A couple changes:

1. You need to check against the cell's `.DisplayFormat` since that is conditional formatting.
2. You were exiting your subroutine before getting to your `If` condition. Use `Exit For` instead.

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Cancel = Not Worksheets(1).CheckBoxes(1).Value = 1

   Dim rng As Range

   For Each rng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
       If rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
           Cancel = True
       Exit For
       End If
   Next rng

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   If Cancel Then MsgBox "Please accept the terms and conditions"

   End Sub
   ```

Also `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` needs to be outside your loop, otherwise it may never be turned back on!

UPDATE:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Cancel = Not Worksheets(1).CheckBoxes(1).Value = 1

Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    If rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
        MsgBox ("Please correct any fields highlighted in red")
        Cancel = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next rng

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If Cancel Then MsgBox "Please accept the terms and conditions before saving the Invoice"

End Sub
```

Comment: Yup, that did it! I just needed to change "If rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then MsgBox ("Please correct fields")" in order to differentiate between the checkbox, and the fields that were highlighted. Other than that, spot on! Thanks!

Comment: Actually I'm running into an issue where not checking the checkbox disables me from saving, which is what I wanted to happen. But if  i check the box, and the highlighted field are present, im still able to save. Any thoughts? Should I declare another variable for the msgbox?

Comment: @MSauce What kind of checkbox is that, an `ActiveX` one right?

Comment: Checkbox, form control.

Comment: @MSauce I can't reproduce the issue, the code works fine for me. Are there multiple pages in your workbook? Maybe you should change `ActiveSheet` to `Worksheets(1)`. Also, your code is in the `ThisWorkbook` module correct? Can you please post your updated code above?

Comment: @MSauce You're missing your `Cancel = True` in that loop right before or after `MsgBox ("Please correct any fields highlighted in red")`.

Comment: Whoop there it is. Thanks!